# Using C# OpCodes to emit method that returns an object

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, object-reference, opcodes

I am creating a dynamic type which has a method that I'd like to return an object.  I am failing to understand how to achieve this. Here's what I have so far:

```
// .. stuff to create type builder



MethodBuilder builder =
                typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
                    method.Name,
                    MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.Public,
                    method.CallingConvention,
                    method.ReturnType,
                    typeArray1);
            builder.InitLocals = true;
ILGenerator gen = builder.GetILGenerator();
Object myObjectIdLikeToReturn = someMethodCall();
//gen.??(??????????) // here's where I'm lost
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

I believe, if I am reading the msdn correct, I need to get the reference of myObjectIdLikeToReturn on the stack--however I've not had luck.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit: To make it more clear. I'm attempting to write the equivalent in IL:

```
public virtual Object MyNewMethod() {
   return myObjectIdLikeToReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this line:

```
Object myObjectIdLikeToReturn = someMethodCall();
```

You say you "want to get the reference to `myObjectIdLikeToReturn` onto the stack."  But that is impossible.  I think you are confusing the timing of when these things are happening.  The IL generation code is analogous to *compiling* -- everything needs to be known statically.  Whereas `myObjectIdLikeToReturn` is a variable that happens to exist while you are generating the code, but would not have any meaning to the class that is actually generated.  You can't "bake in" a reference to some arbitrary runtime object, the idea simply doesn't make any sense.

Your only solution is to somehow make your IL perform the invocation to `someMethodCall`. But without knowing more about where that method lives and its connection to your generated type, it's hard to elaborate on precisely how you'll accomplish that.