# C# Call and return an object from a static method in IL

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit, intermediate-language

This is an extension to the solutions offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606104/using-c-sharp-opcodes-to-emit-method-that-returns-an-object).  I've created a static method that returns me an object.  My goal, is the write a dynamic method for a type I define at runtime to return me the object that this static method is returning. My code thus far:

```
 // type builder and other prep stuff removed for sake of space and reading

private void EmitReferenceMethodBody(Type returnType)
{
    MethodBuilder builder =
    typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
                    method.Name,
                    MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.Public,
                    method.CallingConvention,
                    method.ReturnType,
                    typeArray1);
    builder.InitLocals = true;
    ILGenerator gen = builder.GetILGenerator();
    MethodInfo getStoredObject = typeof(ObjectStore).GetMethod("GetStoredObject",                  BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);        
    MethodInfo getTypeFromHandle = typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle");            

    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, returnType);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getTypeFromHandle);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getStoredObject);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);   
}
```

The updated code now calls the method but appears to be passing the type of the dynamically created type rather then the variable returnType.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least one problem is that you are pushing the "this" reference (`OpCodes.Ldarg_0`) onto the stack even though it is never popped (since you are invoking a *static* method).  I'd try removing that line and see if it behaves better.

Another problem is that you are passing in `new Type[] { returnType }` to the `EmitCall` method.  That is intended for optional arguments (`params`) and I suspect your method actually doesn't have any parameters.  Therefore, you should remove that argument as well.

**Edit:**

Based on comments, you are trying to pass in a `System.Type` object known statically to a method you are invoking dynamically.  This is possible, but you need to jump through a couple of hoops.

1. Get a reference to the `MethodInfo` for the method `Type.GetTypeFromHandle`:

   ```
   MethodInfo getTypeFromHandle = typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle");
   ```
2. Use the following lines of IL to push your `returnType` onto the stack:

   ```
   gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, returnType);
   gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getTypeFromHandle);
   ```

To sum, your code should look like this:

```
MethodInfo getTypeFromHandle = typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle");
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, returnType);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getTypeFromHandle);
gen.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, getStoredObject);                
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

The transitional stack behavior of this code is:

1. Push the `RuntimeTypeHandle` corresponding to the specified `Type` reference onto the stack by using `Opcodes.Ldtoken`.
2. Invoke `getTypeFromHandle` which pops the type handle off the stack, and pushes the actual `System.Type` onto the stack.
3. Call your static method, which will pop the `Type` argument off of the stack and push the return value of your own method onto the stack.
4. Return from the method.

Comment: So removing the load arg 0 emit allows this to call the static method, however I do want to pass the returnType variable to the static method, but it seems to be passing 'this'. When I debug the static method, the param which is of type 'Type' is not the value of returnType, but rather the type of the dynamic class I created.

Comment: Please confirm that your method signature looks like this:  `object GetStoredObject(Type returnType);`.  If so, then you do indeed need to pass in an argument.  However, what `Type` are you actually trying to pass in?

Comment: "public static Object GetStoredObject(Type contract)"   My method above called EmitReferenceMethodBody(Type returnType) gets passed the type i want to pass to my static method.

Comment: Works! Thank you so much. Your explanation was very intuitive!

Answer (score 1):

Expression trees might be a better solution here. It's pretty easy to create a `Func<Type, object>` using dynamic typing through expressions.

```
ParameterExpression paramEx = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Type), "paramObject");
Expression callExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(ObjectStore), "GetStoredObject", null, paramEx);
Expression<Func<Type, object>> funcExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Type, object>>(callExpression, paramEx);
Func<Type, object> actualFunc = funcExpression.Compile();
```

Now if the ObjectStore requires generic parameters, you would replace `typeof(ObjectStore)` with `typeof(ObjectStore).MakeGenericType(returnType)`. If the `GetStoredObject` function itself requires generic parameters, then you would change the `null` in the `Expression.Call` statement to `new Type[] { returnType }`. If this is generated once for each type you pass in and you plan on using this a lot, then it might be a good idea to cache these Funcs into a `Dictionary<Type, Func<Type, object>>` and only build it once (as compiling Expressions repeatedly is a waste of system resources).